# What is the proper way to reference a user interaction on Android?

Tags: android, documentation

I'm currently in the process of writing documentation for an app, and was curious of the proper way to reference a user interaction on screen.

```
i.e.: To advance to the settings screen, tap/touch/click the settings icon.
```

Since Android is available on so many form-factors, including TV, is it 'tap' or 'touch' or 'click' or something else entirely that maybe encompasses everything?  I've checked some other app docs and they all vary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the SDK *(agreed, this is for developers, and not end-users)* seems to be using the **touch** word.

See for example the [**Handling UI Events**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) section, in which you'll find *(quoting)* :

> This is called when **the user either
>   touches the item** (when in touch
>   mode), or focuses upon the item with
>   the navigation-keys or trackball and
>   presses the suitable "enter" key or
>   presses down on the trackball.

Or :

> For a touch-capable device, **once the
>   user touches the screen**, the device
>   will enter touch mode.

Comment: Thanks.. as this is geared for developers (see [touch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#TouchMode) from the same page), i'm still not sure if  'touch' is the correct term for end-user documentation. :/